# Associative matrix c++ too big

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, 2d

Where is a way to reduce size of matrix? (x2 array)
for example, i have only to store data (0, 1, 2) into array
but elements can be up to 250 000.?
is there a way to store values, like in dictionary.. ?

```
const int MAX = 250000;
short data[MAX][MAX] = {};//wont compile..
```

Comment: `std::unordered_map<unsigned int, std::array<unsigned char, MAX>>` would be my initial thought.

Comment: *i have only to store data (0, 1, 2) into array but elements can be up to 250 000* This is very unclear.  What are the dimensions of the matrix?  What is the {min, max} range of the values?  How many nonzero elements per row/column?

Comment: values can be ONLY 0, 1, 2
but keys can be up to 250 000, for example data[249043][245235] = 0

Comment: You ask about dictionaries... does this mean `data[i][j]` is not defined for lots of `i`s and `j`s?

Comment: yes, it can be not defined for all range from 0..250 000

Comment: then you should use `std::unordered_map<unsigned int, std::unordered_map<unsigned int, unsigned char>> data;` when you do `data[32424][3243242] = 2` it takes care of business... I'll answer below.

Answer (score 2):

This worked perfectly for me, as I commented above ([live here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf0ec70c69071932)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

std::unordered_map<unsigned int, std::unordered_map<unsigned int, unsigned char>> data;

int main() {
  std::cout << "oi" << std::endl;

    data[232432][234234] = 2;
    data[2][2] = 1;
    std::cout << int(data[232432][234234]) << std::endl;
    std::cout << int(data[3][3]) << std::endl;
    std::cout << int(data[232432][1]) << std::endl;
    std::cout << int(data[2][2]) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: perfect! but to maintain compatibility not only for c++11? : )

Answer (score 1):

As I remember there are some limitations for the sizeof of static variable. Use dynamic memory.
You can use different type of storage depending on number of elements and memory limitations.

1. Sparse matrix could be used when number of elements is less than some predefined value, in other words data density is low. 
   The idea for sparse matrix is simple: you do not keep all possible elements; instead you keep plain array of some big number of elements, lets say 1000, of type struct {int line, row; unsigned char value;}. Up to some value, memory consumption of such array is less than matrix.  But it can be significant overhead on random access. Some optimization could be applied to reduce it.
2. If data density is hight, the number of "active" elements are big, some effect could be achieved with compacted matrix, bit-packing in use. This could be very effective by memory. In you example you need only 2 bits per value, so int64 will keep 32 values in a "row". Fine-optimized access method required here to reduce time consumption.
3. You can switch between above solutions to migrate from sparse matrix to compacted matrix.

Answer (score 1):

If the data is very sparse, then [Massa's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22996836/1329652) has the overhead of an extra `unordered_map` per each item. A lower overhead solution would be to index the unordered map with pairs:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

/// Hash specialization for a pair of unsigned ints
template<> struct std::hash<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>>
{
  typedef std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> argument_type;
  typedef std::size_t value_type;
  value_type operator()(argument_type const& s) const
  {
    value_type const h1 ( std::hash<unsigned int>()(s.first) );
    value_type const h2 ( std::hash<unsigned int>()(s.second) );
    return h1 ^ (h2 << 1);
  }
};

std::unordered_map<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, unsigned char> data;

int main() {
  using std::make_pair;
  data[make_pair(232432u, 234234u)] = 2;
  data[make_pair(2u, 3u)] = 1;
  std::cout << int(data[make_pair(232432u, 234234u)]) << std::endl;
  std::cout << int(data[make_pair(3u, 3u)]) << std::endl;
  std::cout << int(data[make_pair(232432u, 1u)]) << std::endl;
  std::cout << int(data[make_pair(2u, 3u)]) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: it's good, but also compatibility not only to c++11? and what about searching value?

Answer (score 0):

**Compression**
You can compress the data values, which will save you memory but increase the access time.

Your value range: 0, 1, 2, takes up 2 bits to represent.  So an 8-bit, uint8_t, variable could hold 4 columns of values:

```
 3  2  1  0  
+--+--+--+--+  
|xx|xx|xx|xx|  
+--+--+--+--+
```

To access the values, you would need to perform some binary arithmetic:

```
value of column 0 == (byte & 0x03); /* >> 0 */
value of column 1 == (byte & 0x0c) >> 2;  
value of column 2 == (byte & 0x30) >> 4;
value of column 3 == (byte & 0xC0) >> 6;
```

The byte would be accessed by:  `(index / 4)`

**Change of perspective**
Since you have only 3 values, you could store the coordinates in a list in an array.  You would search the array for the coordinates.

```
Data        row   col       row   col
+---+     +-----+----+     +-----+---+   
| 0 | --> | 115 | 25 | --> |20961| 4 |  
+---+     +-----+----+     +-----+---+  
| 1 |  
+---+  
| 2 |  
+---+
```

In the above illustration, matrix position [115][25] contains a zero, as well as [20961][4].

In the above technique, you could compress the matrix positions by using ranges.

Comment: it's good idea, but what about searching? does it take a longer time to get value for key-key indexes?

Comment: You will have to profile it.  The efficiency of most search and sort algorithms depend on the data to some extent.